# Unit test nested promise angularjs/jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, jasmine2.0

I am trying following snippet code, to simplify it, I have removed most of the unwanted code.

```js
function functionToTest() {
  if(hasUnsavedChanges()){
    return customService.confirm().then(function(confirmed) {
      console.log(confirmed);
      if(confirmed) {
        return customService.openSomething().then(function (data){
          console.log(data);
          return customService.doneSomething();
        });
      } else {
        return customService.doSomething().then(function (){
          return customService.doSomethingBeforeDone().then(function (){
            return customService.doneSomething();
          });
        });
      }  
    }, function() {
      return customService.doneSomething();
    });
  } else {
    return customService.doneSomething();
  }
}
```

Here is my unit test when hasUnsavedChanges() returns true

```js
it('should doSomething', function() {
  spyOn(customService, 'confirm').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
  spyOn(customService, 'openSomething').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({data: 'something'}));
  spyOn(customService, 'doneSomething').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
  
  functionToTest();
  $scope.$apply();
  
  expect(customService.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(customService.openSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(customService.doneSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

customService.confirm is being called but the other 2 asserts are not being called.

Although I can see that console.log(confirmed) and console.log(data) are showing correct values which are being returned through spies

Answer (score 0):

Asserting in then block of my function call fixed it

```js
it('should doSomething', function() {
  spyOn(customService, 'confirm').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
  spyOn(customService, 'openSomething').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({data: 'something'}));
  spyOn(customService, 'doneSomething').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
  
  functionToTest().then(function() {
    expect(customService.confirm).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(customService.openSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(customService.doneSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });  
});
```